# Truffle installation error: "install latest visual studio version"

Tags: visual-studio, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

[image]

I've installed latest version of visual studio with desktop development c++ workload but still they are asking for it when i try to install truffle.
I entered command :npm install -g truffle
and lot of messages appear after 2 to 3 minutes of some kind of installation process.
they are asking for Latest version of Visual Studio with "Desktop development with c++ workload" whereas i just installed my Visual studio with the same requirements.
node.js and ganache are already installed.
Is there any other way to install truffle?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Try version 5.4.29
Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842716/getting-error-on-installing-truffle-on-windows-10-using-npm-install-truffle-g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are installing it using npm package manager. Downgrade your npm to 7.24.2 it worked for me I hope it will also work for you. Use the following command to downgrade npm

```
npm install -g npm@7.24.2
```