# Truffle installation error - cannot find visual studio installation

Tags: npm, truffle

I have been trying to install truffle for some time, but I keep getting the following gyp error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Miri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\keccak
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.18.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Users\Miri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2022
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - will only use this version
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS unknown version "undefined" found at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1974) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version does not match this VS Command Prompt or the
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS installation cannot be used.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Miri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Miri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Miri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Miri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Miri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Miri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Miri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:390:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Miri\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Miri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\keccak
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Miri\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-27T12_19_08_825Z-debug.log
```

I have already looked at [Getting Error on installing Truffle on windows 10 using npm install truffle -g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842716/getting-error-on-installing-truffle-on-windows-10-using-npm-install-truffle-g) but the error there is diferent. See `unknown version "undefined" found at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community` this line(15).

I already have Visual Studio 2022 Community installed.

Does anyone know what this error is and how to resolve it?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Some issue...any joy fixing it?

Comment: Could not make installation through npm. However I copied the truffle folder from another pc where installation was successful and pasted in global node_modules. It worked.