# Electron error when trying to install Truffle

Tags: node.js, electron, smartcontracts, truffle

When I try install truffle using npm install -g truffle@5.4.29 I get a warning that there are 15 vunerabilities (10 moderate, 4 high and 1 critical). When I run npm audit fix I get the following errors

[image]

> electron  <=13.6.3 Severity: high
>
> Context isolation bypass via leaked cross-context objects in Electron - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-m93v-9qjc-3g79
>
> Sandboxed renderers can obtain thumbnails of arbitrary files through
> the nativeImage API - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-mpjm-v997-c4h4
>
> IPC messages delivered to the wrong frame in Electron -
> https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hvf8-h2qh-37m9
>
> Context isolation bypass via Promise in Electron -
> https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-6vrv-94jv-crrg
>
> Renderers can obtain access to random bluetooth device without
> permission in Electron -
> https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3p22-ghq8-v749
>
> fix available via `npm audit fix`
>
> node_modules/electron-eval/node_modules/electron
>
> electron-eval  >=0.9.8
> Depends on vulnerable versions of electron
> node_modules/electron-eval

the version of electron installed is 19.0.3

I've tried to uninstall electron and change the version but nothing is working, I'm not sure why electron is installed, I don't think I have used it for anything

Thanks
Noelle

Comment: Have you tried w/ the current Truffle? There’s a transitive dependency on `electron-eval` somewhere, that is what pulls in Electron.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton trying the current truffle version gives a load of errors, that I think have something to do with VS code

Comment: Without understanding what the errors are, or how VSCode is involved, there's no real way to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of truffle requires c++ development tools as per this SO question [Getting Error on installing Truffle on windows 10 using npm install truffle -g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842716/getting-error-on-installing-truffle-on-windows-10-using-npm-install-truffle-g)

I think there may have been some compatibility issues, I had versions of VS from 2005 and onwards on my machine. The only solution I could come up with was to remove all instances of Visual Studio, I was then able to install truffle version 5.4.29 without issue. I have since installed VS code and it works grand.